# why cannot run pyspark in jupyter notebook ,mac os

Tags: macos, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I downloaded apache pyspark through brew download and also tried download directly from https://spark.apache.org/. But after download I tried type "pyspark" directly in terminal and countered this errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esLaI.png)

I also tried all the steps that are available in this manual: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-mac-pyspark-453f395f240b. But also get error when run spark in jupyter notebook, which are:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE879.png)

Comment: from my experience the easiest way is to install pyspark via pip (even in anaconda). This has always worked for me and is very convenient

Answer (score 1):

in your screenshot the error is at line 14, you have not imported sparksession. Sparksession in not a pyspark function.

Add : 
     from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
to your code, it might give others as per your script but will fix this one.
Please share your script as well.